# Powershell to take ownership and delete a folder based on samaccountname

Tags: powershell

Need to take ownership/delete folders/files in a unc path based on samaccountname

```
Foreach ($line in $users){
  Get-Aduser -identity $line.DistinguishedName | Select samaccountname
  $username = $line.samaccountname
  takeown /a /r /d y /f "\\fileserver\share\$username"
  Remove-Item "\\fileserver\share\$username"}
```

The above attempts to take ownership of everything in \\fileserver\share and I need it to only take ownership/remove the $username folder/subfolders. Also, need to be able to do a -whatif properly to see what will happen before it does.  Thank you!

Comment: I feel like you're skipping a step. You `Get-ADUser`, but you don't store the results. I think you want those results for setting `$username` instead of setting it from `$line.samaccountname`. So maybe `$ADUser = Get-aduser -iden...` and then `$username = $ADUser.samaccountname`?

Comment: @themadtechnician ok that makes sense. Would that prevent it from trying to take ownership of \\servername\share instead of \\servername\share\$username ?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon so what would the code for that look like using Set-ACL?

Comment: Yes, because `$username` would be blank, which makes `"\\fileserver\share\$username"` read as just `"\\fileserver\share\"`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon `Get-Acl` and `Set-Acl` can have trouble processing files if the owner is missing or the account is broken. I've run into issues trying to get ownership using `Set-Acl` before and had to use alternative methods.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician yeah, I deleted my comment, I have no experience taking ownership of network shares with `Set-ACL`. For AD Objects works perfect tho, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the root of your problem is that your source CSV likely doesn't have a `samaccountname` column so your line `$username = $line.samaccountname` is setting `$username` to `$null`. To fix that save the result of your `Get-ADUser` call, then reference that instead.

```
Foreach ($line in $users){
  $ADUser = Get-Aduser -identity $line.DistinguishedName | Select samaccountname
  $username = $ADUser.samaccountname
  takeown /a /r /d y /f "\\fileserver\share\$username"
  Remove-Item "\\fileserver\share\$username"}
```

That's it, that's my answer, the rest is just extra stuff I feel applies to the situation and might be helpful.

I've had issues trying to get ownership of files and folder before when NTFS owners were missing or corrupted (like an account is deleted and all that's left as the owner is a SID that points at nothing). Here's the function I keep on hand in case of such troublesome cases (I'm aware the verb on the function is not an approved verb, but it makes me smile so it stays!):

```
Function PWN-Item{
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
    $Path
)
Begin{
If(!$Script:PWNInit){
#P/Invoke'd C# code to enable required privileges to take ownership and make changes when NTFS permissions are lacking
$AdjustTokenPrivileges = @"
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

 public class TokenManipulator
 {
  [DllImport("advapi32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
  internal static extern bool AdjustTokenPrivileges(IntPtr htok, bool disall,
  ref TokPriv1Luid newst, int len, IntPtr prev, IntPtr relen);
  [DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]
  internal static extern IntPtr GetCurrentProcess();
  [DllImport("advapi32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
  internal static extern bool OpenProcessToken(IntPtr h, int acc, ref IntPtr
  phtok);
  [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
  internal static extern bool LookupPrivilegeValue(string host, string name,
  ref long pluid);
  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
  internal struct TokPriv1Luid
  {
   public int Count;
   public long Luid;
   public int Attr;
  }
  internal const int SE_PRIVILEGE_DISABLED = 0x00000000;
  internal const int SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED = 0x00000002;
  internal const int TOKEN_QUERY = 0x00000008;
  internal const int TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES = 0x00000020;
  public static bool AddPrivilege(string privilege)
  {
   try
   {
    bool retVal;
    TokPriv1Luid tp;
    IntPtr hproc = GetCurrentProcess();
    IntPtr htok = IntPtr.Zero;
    retVal = OpenProcessToken(hproc, TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, ref htok);
    tp.Count = 1;
    tp.Luid = 0;
    tp.Attr = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
    retVal = LookupPrivilegeValue(null, privilege, ref tp.Luid);
    retVal = AdjustTokenPrivileges(htok, false, ref tp, 0, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
    return retVal;
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
    throw ex;
   }
  }
  public static bool RemovePrivilege(string privilege)
  {
   try
   {
    bool retVal;
    TokPriv1Luid tp;
    IntPtr hproc = GetCurrentProcess();
    IntPtr htok = IntPtr.Zero;
    retVal = OpenProcessToken(hproc, TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, ref htok);
    tp.Count = 1;
    tp.Luid = 0;
    tp.Attr = SE_PRIVILEGE_DISABLED;
    retVal = LookupPrivilegeValue(null, privilege, ref tp.Luid);
    retVal = AdjustTokenPrivileges(htok, false, ref tp, 0, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
    return retVal;
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
    throw ex;
   }
  }
 }
"@
add-type $AdjustTokenPrivileges
#Activate necessary admin privileges to make changes without NTFS perms
[void][TokenManipulator]::AddPrivilege("SeRestorePrivilege") #Necessary to set Owner Permissions
[void][TokenManipulator]::AddPrivilege("SeBackupPrivilege") #Necessary to bypass Traverse Checking
[void][TokenManipulator]::AddPrivilege("SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege") #Necessary to override FilePermissions
$Script:PWNInit = $True
}
#Obtain a copy of the initial ACL
#$FSOACL = Get-ACL $FSO - gives error when run against a folder with no admin perms or ownership

}
Process{
ForEach($Item in $Path){
$FSO = Get-Item $Item
#Create a new ACL object for the sole purpose of defining a new owner, and apply that update to the existing folder's ACL
$NewOwnerACL = If($FSO -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]){New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity}else{New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSecurity}
#Establish the folder as owned by BUILTIN\Administrators, guaranteeing the following ACL changes can be applied
$Admin = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("BUILTIN\Administrators")
$NewOwnerACL.SetOwner($Admin)
#Merge the proposed changes (new owner) into the file/folder's actual ACL
$FSO.SetAccessControl($NewOwnerACL)

#Add full control for administrators
$Rights = [System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights]"FullControl" 
$InheritanceFlag = If($FSO -is [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]){[System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]"ObjectInherit,ContainerInherit"}else{[System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::None}
$PropagationFlag = [System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]::None 
$objType =[System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow 
$objACE = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($Admin, $Rights, $InheritanceFlag, $PropagationFlag, $objType) 
#Get fresh copy of ACL
$objACL = Get-Acl $FSO.FullName
#Clear any DENY rules for the local admin group
$objACL.Access|?{$_.IdentityReference -eq $admin -and $_.AccessControlType -eq [System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Deny}|%{$objACL.RemoveAccessRule($_)}
#Add Full Control here
$objACL.AddAccessRule($objACE)
#Set updated ACL
Set-Acl $FSO.FullName $objACL
}
}
}
```

You can just feed it paths and it'll take care of them all. Example usage:

```
"\\fileserver\share\jim","\\fileserver\share\bob","\\fileserver\share\mark"|PWN-Item
```

or

```
PWN-Item "\\fileserver\share\$username"
```

Comment: So if the user's samAccountName is "WShattner" are you trying to take ownership of the file/folder "fileserver\share\WShattner.v2"?

Comment: that was it! ok one other question would takeown /a /r /d y /f "\\fileserver\share\$username.v2" work for a folder that was the username .v2?

Comment: yes samaccountname is  "WShattner" trying to take ownership of the file/folder "\\fileserver\share\Wshattner.v2"

Comment: Thanks man! That helped a lot. Now the final part is to Remove-Item "\\servername\share\$username" and again for $username.v2.